# Copy last row between A and I to row below

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to look for the last row of data between column A and I and then duplicate the value to the row below which is empty.

Every time I run it, Excel crashes

```
Sub insert_row()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow = LastRow

Dim lastrow_start As String
Dim lastrow_end As String
lastrow_start = "A" & LastRow
lastrow_end = "I" & LastRow

Dim lastrowregion As String
lastrowregion = lastrow_start & ":" & lastrow_end

Dim lastrowrange As Range
Set lastrowrange = Range(lastrowregion)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(lastrow_start)

Do While (rng.Value <> "")
    rng.Offset(1).insert
    lastrowrange.Copy rng.Offset(1)
    Set lastrowrange = rng.Offset(2)
Loop

End Sub
```

Is it just copying too much and causing a crash? It's only nine columns and they're all text apart from one cell which is a shape (button).

Comment: **1** lastrowregion is a string. Use `Set rng = Range(lastrowregion)` **2** Use `.Find` to find the last row as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: For the error, `lastrowregion` is a String which is what the message is trying to convey.

Comment: You should define all your variables too since you're encountering type errors.

Comment: I've updated the original post with a new error - thanks for the help around setting it as a range correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set a `String` to a range object. To get the range use:

```
Set rng = Range(lastrowregion)
```

The Range you are getting is `A2:I2`. So your `Do While` will error because `rng.Value` is actually returning an Array. You could either loop through either the Range or the Array at that point if you intended on it being multiple cells.

---

If the goal is simply to copy the last row of data down one row then this method can be much simpler. You can simply set the `Offset` to equal the value of the last row. Since they are the same size it will just work.

To show this I used `CurrentRegion` but you could also do it with your `A2:I2` Range.

```
Public Sub copyLastRowDown()
    Dim region As Range
    Set region = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    With region.Rows(region.Rows.Count)
        .Offset(1).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Additional Notes**

- Use [Option Explicit](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#use-option-explicit) to ensure all variables are explicitly declared.
- Declare and assign variables next to where they are going to be used, but place them in a [reasonable place](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#declare-variables-where-used%22).
- Do not use [underscore case](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#underscore--case) as this has special meaning with events and interfaces.

Comment: That makes sense - the issue I'm having now is Excel crashes when I execute the code. I think the code is correct now but I can't actually see the results as it crashes. (I've updated original post with code)

Comment: Maybe there's an alternative to Copy and Pasting? I don't mind the values of the inserted row not being exactly the same, it can insert placeholder text for example, but I figured copy/paste would be easier as there is a shape in one cell that is assigned to a macro.

Comment: You have an infinite loop. Why do you even need a `Do Loop`? Are you just trying to get the last row to copy down one row?

Comment: Yeah, that or what i described in my previous comment

Comment: I added an example to my answer. When working with the same sized Range you can simply set one range equal to the other. This is almost always better than copy and paste.

Comment: Got it to work - your code is much more efficient than copy/paste for sure, thanks! The only problem with it is that it doesn't duplicate the shape (button macro) that is within the row like a copy/paste does - any ideas for a work around?

Comment: Glad you got it to work! That sounds like a separate question to this one. You can ask another question and reference this one in the post.

Comment: Resolved it but having the code insert the shape each time, rather than duplicate it from the previous row - seems all good now! Thanks once again for your help